# ArcGIS Symbology For OSM Street Flow Directions

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, openstreetmap, symbology

I have downloaded OSM data in `[.shp.zip]` format from [geofabrik.de](http://download.geofabrik.de/north-america.html) now I need to apply Street map symbology to them. Can you please let me know how I can display the flow direction symbol in the street layer?

[image]

Comment: related https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/98435/does-osm-data-contain-the-direction-of-travel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Making your map look exactly like the OSM renderer is a little more complex, but in basic terms, what you want to do is **symbolize by unique values of ONEWAY** and then vary your **Cartographic Line Symbol Properties** when `ONEWAY = 1`.

In your layer's symbology, categorize by **Categories/ Unique values/ Value Field = ONEWAY**.

[image: layer properties screenshot]

Edit the symbol for the condition where ONEWAY = 1 by double-clicking on that symbol. Choose **Edit Symbol/ Line Properties** and make sure your **Type** is set to **Cartographic Line Symbol**. Choose a **Line Decoration** of a right-pointing arrow.

[image: symbol property editor screenshot]

Click the **Properties** button. Under **Line Decoration/ Number of positions**, increase the number of positions as necessary.

[image: line decoration editor screenshot]

Click the **Symbol** button to make the arrowhead smaller and vary its color.

[image]

Drill further into the symbol's properties by clicking **Edit Symbol**, and you can customize even more - there are tons of options for adding components to the marker. Sample output:

[image: sample map output]

Comment: fyi and -1 would be a left direction arrow.